# Two-way SelectedText binding on TextBox using inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, selectedtext

I'm trying to replace the SelectedText of a TextBox with a new value by binding on the custom property 'Selected'. Currently, updating Selected through binding doesn't change the actual SelectedText. I'm almost there I think; at least mouse-selecting text is updating Selected.

I'd prefer solutions based on inheriting from TextBox if possible. 
Can anybody tell me what's missing please?

```
class SelectionTextbox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Selection", typeof(string), typeof(SelectionTextbox));

    public string Selection
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base.GetValue(SelectionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(SelectionProperty, value);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        Selection = SelectedText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you never actually do anything with the value you assign to `Selection`. You need to actually make it the selected text.

```
public string Selection
{
    get
    {
        return (string)base.GetValue(SelectionProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(SelectionProperty, value);
        if(value != SelectedText)
            SelectedText = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Binding to update the source you have to specify `Mode=TwoWay` if you want to reflect changes back to code. This can be done by two ways:

```
Selection="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

or by

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Selection",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(SelectionTextbox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

By using the second method you have that all bindings to `Selection` are done `TwoWay` and you do not have to specify it explicitly.