# Bind selected text in TextBox to the view model in WPF and by MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, textbox, selectedtext

I am new to WPF and MVVM. 
I have a TextBox with some lines of text. I want to bind a piece of text highlighted by a user, to my ViewModel.
How can I do this without coding in code behind?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please include what have you tried so far to your question?

Comment: please make a google search and try something befor posting, stack overflow used to be good...

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32516738/1136211

Comment: @ErwinDraconis I already searched on google and I did not find the way to do this with mvvm.

Comment: @SamTheDev in fact, I open a text file in a textbox and after that I select a word from text. I have to return this selected word to a method in my viewmodel. I work with MVVM architecture and I have nothing in the Xaml code behind.
I found the answers that use the code behind to do this binding but in my case, I should to respect completely to MVVM architecture.

Comment: Well, you have to try something first (maybe following the link that @Clemens suggested), StackOverflow isn't a code on-demand platform ^^

Comment: @SamTheDev thanks for your comments but they are not very useful.

Comment: @SaraSheikhi here is how to do it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245928/mvvm-and-the-textboxs-selectedtext-property

Comment: @ErwinDraconis Yes, it is probably the solution that I haven't tried yest. thank you

Comment: @Clemens, I haven't heard about DependencyProperty! that solved my peorblem.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Clemens I have a problem,  I did exactly Thomas Levesque's solution but It doesn't work, I put breakpoints for all of functions in TextBoxHelper but none of them is called when I select a text. I would like to know if there is something more to do to make it work?

Answer (score -4):

You cannot directly bind your selected text to a property. You have to implement a DependencyProperty and attach that but this is not trivial for beginners. A good explanation is here:
[MVVM and the TextBox's SelectedText property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246190/12063196)

Comment: The `Binding.Target` must be a `DependencyProperty`. The `Binding.Source` can be any public property with a getter where `BindingMode.TwoWay` and `BindingMode.OneWayToSource` requires a setter too. To make `BindingMode.TwoWay` work properly the class of the binding source must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event with the property's name as event argument when the value of the property has changed.

Comment: I know the requirements for binding very well and you described the basics, which do not apply here because you cannot bind the `SelectedText` property of the `TextBox` to a property because it is not a `DependencyProperty`. This is why you have to attach your own `DependencyProperty` to get access to the `TextBox::SelectedText` property. Besides that, the solution I linked to does not extend the `TextBox` in the ViewModel. Maybe you mean the solution which is linked in the comments to the question?
Edit: The comment I'm answering to seems to be deleted...

Comment: @Mihaeru, Thanks for your answer,  I did exactly what Thomas Levesque said in your link but It doesn't work, I put breakpoints for all of functions in TextBoxHelper but none of them is called when I select a text. I would like to know if there is something more to do to make it work?

Comment: Have you set your SelectedText property to an initial value? If it is null, the behavior will be detached in SelectedTextChanged.

Comment: @Sara Sheikhi to be more specific, the bound property in your ViewModel should be initialized and implemented like following:

    `private string _selectedText = string.Empty;  
    public string SelectedText  
    {  
        get { return _selectedText; }  
        set  
        {  
            _selectedText = value;  
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedText);  
        }  
   }`

Comment: @Mihaeru thank you so much, problem is solved by your answer.